# How do I install latest libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller (GIT HEAD rev)

Tags: compiling, deb, git

Unfortunately the standard packages in the Ubuntu repository for ideviceinstaller/libimobiledevice and it's dependency are at the moment useless because they are so heavily outdated (even for Ubuntu 20.04) that they do not work for iOS 13.x devices.

Therefore I am searching way to install to get the [latest libimobiledevice version from Github](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice), compile it, make a deb from it.
The main problem is that libimobiledevice can't be updated without also updating it's dependencies:

- [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist)
- [libusbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd)
- [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)
- [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd)

I don't want to mess around with directly installing those packages via `make install` as it messes up the system and does not work anyway (no devices can be found after building & installing those packages).

**Is there a simple way to clone those repositories, build deb files and install them?**

On other platforms like MacOS this is a simple task via `brew` and a few commands, is there also a simple way on Ubuntu)?

Addendum: I have already tried the source packages of the upcoming groovy, but they are newer but don't use the latest version from GIT and often end up in compile errors (while the latest versions from Github compile fine).

Comment: Robert, you might try using the script on the link below. It was created by one of the developers who maintains the libimobiledevice toolset. https://gist.github.com/nikias/e72902570cca679e752a7076a6b2127e
Cheers, Andy